# Creating, Finding, and Uploading Binary File

Tags: ios

Can somebody make this simple for me please? My goal is to upload a binary file to the Apple Connect store. Every time I read one instruction, it says to follow a previous instruction, and always from some assumed context that they don't explain how to get to.

First Confusion:
To Submit an Archive to the App Store
1. In the Archives organizer, select the archive.
2. Click the Distribute button.

Well, I finally found the Archives organizer, but I have no Distribute button. Just a white screen that says 'No Archives'.

Second Confusion:
How do I create an archive and where is it stored? My scheme shows that I am building for Archive, but I can't find the archive. My preferences take me to an Archives folder, but it is empty.

What an unnecessarily convoluted process. Can somebody tell me what I am overlooking? Thanks!

Comment: Read the [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582). The [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/About.html) is also very handy.

Comment: Can u post screenshot of XCode after creating Archive. with the error message.

Comment: You could find step by step tutorial
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816828/app-submission-binary-does-not-show-up-in-itunesconnect/25816865#25816865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`What an unnecessarily convoluted process. Can somebody tell me what I am overlooking? Thanks!`

Oh man, do I agree.  Just wait until you have to renew your yearly distribution certificate...

Ok, now to helping.  In order to create an archive you need to have it setup like you are going to run on a device (even if you don't have a device plugged it, it will say "IOS Device").  Then you need to go to the top-bar menu and select Product->Archive.  That will create an archive for you and will automatically open the Organizer window.  In that window you should now have an archive.  When you click on that archive you will now have options for "Validate" and "Distribute".

One thing of note, make sure your debug target is not set to a simulator.  It will not let you archive unless you have is set to "IOS Device"

Comment: Thanks. I actually just figured that out, too. Why can't all of their App Distribution guides just effing say this! And now I have another problem: "No identities available for signing". Apple = overrated.

Comment: That problem is in your build settings of the project.  Look for a "code signing" setting in that huge list and make sure that your "release" and "App Store" have valid code signing identities.  Those identities need to be created in the "IOS dev center".  Then you need to create an App in "Itunes Connect".  Then, and only then, can you start thinking you are somewhere close to releasing an app...

Comment: Thank you again. I found "release" and gave it a code signing identity. I do not see "App Store" anywhere. I do see "debug", which I also gave a code signing identity. Same issue persists with "No identities available for signing". BTW, my bundle id's match between XCode and iTunes Connect.