# App submission binary does not show up in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I want to update my app. I have a new version of the app and now it says "Prepare for Submission".

Now I want to perform "Prepare for Upload" but I cannot find this in the new iTunes Connect.

I have tried to upload the app to iTunes using Application Loader and Xcode 5.1 but still the status hasn’t changed and when I click on "Submit For Review" I get the following error:

> You must choose a build.

Comment: Please check your icloud email inbox for a message regarding your IPA upload. Might help.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It is quite weird but let me show what I have learnt from this new **iTunnesConnect** layout.

**Step 1**: You should wait around 10 min to 20 min to see your uploaded binary file in the prerelease section. [image] .

**Step 2**: After you wait a while (10-20 min) then you would see the below icon [image]

**Step 3**: Then you could able to see that your binary is ready. [image]

**Step 4**: Then click on plus (+) sign, you now could able to choose your binary and then click submit for review button to finalize.
 [image]

Comment: Hi @casillas !  Just to be clear ... http://stackoverflow.com/q/26143661/294884 you had to wait EVEN FOR THE "PRERELEASE" TO APPEAR ... is that right? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Joe,It appears at the same time.

Comment: Gotchya thanks - there is some problem in our case then.

Comment: Just to add my 2 cents, it only took about 3 minutes for me :D

Comment: Initially, it was taking longer. But I believe Apple has fixed the duration somehow. Now, It takes short amount of time (3-5 min)

Comment: As of 9/18/15, the wait was approximately 30 minutes. Could be something on Apple's end, but for those not seeing the build appear.. perhaps just wait a bit longer.

Comment: Took about ~4-5 minutes on 9/7/2016

Answer (score 15):

Look for it here:

[image]

Here's the new binary I uploaded:
[image]

Then, don't forget to create a new version and then assign the new binary to it (after process is completed):
[image]

Comment: If you didn't know that you have to select "+ VERSION OR PLATFORM" then you'd be waiting a lot longer than 19min.  So Thx a lot for this tidbit.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem, and waited for more than 8 hours without any result. The plus-icon never showed up under the build section!

Then I saw a new (tax-agreement) contract that I had not signed. I signed it, waited for a few more minutes, and then the plus-icon showed up!

Comment: where is the (tax agreement) contact . I have buli and uploaded two times but it is not showing.

Comment: @NiroshanRanapathi , The page itunesconnect.apple.com redirects you to a the main page where "Agreements, Tax, and Banking" is one of the options.

Comment: I am waiting long time but build is not visible here. My app is 100% free . agreement , tax are compulsory for every app

Comment: @karthi i uploaded app again with new version number then appear app on itunes

Answer (score 3):

The reason could also be that you are still releasing binary with the old TestFlight SDK in it.

A few months ago TestFlight updated their service meaning that it is now included in iTunesConnect, previously a TestFlightSDK was included in the project and various codes needed to enable TestFlight for users. This is all now depreciated. This means if you release a new version of an app which still has the TestFlightSDK included your binary won't appear in iTunes Connect and you will receive an email like this:

*We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "blahApp". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:*

*TestFlight SDK - TestFlight no longer requires an SDK to enable beta testing, crash reporting and analytics. To continue using TestFlight, set up Beta Testing in iTunes Connect and remove references to the SDK from the following executables: blahApp.app/blahApp*

*Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.*

You need to remove the TestFlightSDK and also all code linked to the old TestFlight. Once this is done the binary should start being picked up by iTunes Connect as the answer above states.

The tricky thing about this issue is that if you're like me the email could go through to your junk, to an old account or if you're working for a client and don't have access to their personal email it is tough to find. Apple give you no other indication that this is what's wrong.

Hope this helps people with this problem going forward

Answer (score 2):

Just took 19 minutes.  If you click the activity tab you can see that the upload is processing.

Answer (score 0):

At this time of writing, binary submission should take only few minutes to appear in iTunesConnect. When my binary did not show up for hours, I can immediately tell that something is not right. Most of the answers I found resolved to waiting. This was not the case for me. I went to ask Apple support and I got the answer. My app was missing purpose string for one of my protected data class (for iOS 10 and later). Once I provided the usage description and resubmitted it, the binary shows up right away.

I thought someone else might be facing the same problem. For a complete list of protected data class that requires descriptions, check out this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1937/_index.html