# During ios app submission to appstore/itunesconnect, getting warning as "Build xxxx does not contain the correct beta entitlement"

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, appstore-approval, mobile-application

I have uploaded my first ever ios app 1 week before and it is in "waiting for review" status. Today i came to notice that when i clicked on "Prerelease" it is giving warning as "Build 1.1 does not contain the correct beta entitlement. For more information, see the iTunes Connect Developer Guide."

Can anyone pls let me know what will happen to my app? it will be approved or get rejected? since it is a warinig not error and i successfully uploaded this with this...

I came to solution that i need to recreate distribution provisioning profile and rebuild my app and resubmit... but it will again take 1 week to "review" so i dont want to go for that.

Anyone have come accross this issue please let me know what will be best solution for me... I am very much worried as i have only this week for this app to make it live.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [App "does not contain the correct beta entitlement"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756669/app-does-not-contain-the-correct-beta-entitlement)

Comment: Check the following answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816828/app-submission-binary-does-not-show-up-in-itunesconnect/25816865#25816865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Apple created a new entitlement that is added when you regenerate your distribution certificate.

If your app is already "Waiting for Review", it should be fine.

If you want this warning to go away:

Regenerate you Provisioning Profile, download it, rebuild your IPA and upload the new Archived Binary.

Comment: Thanks dear....

I am very very happy to say that my app is "Ready for sale".. ohhh... its really a wonderful feeling....my 1st app and it is approved....

That warning doesn't make any effect on my app approval...

Answer (score 0):

Please make the file Entitlements.plist in your project Bundle and then paste this source. And after that just make a fresh build and upload the binary once again by changing the build no. Its not necessary to change the Version No.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>aps-environment</key>
        <string>production</string>
        <key>get-task-allow</key>
        <false/>
        <key>beta-reports-active</key>
        <true/>
        <key>application-identifer</key>
        <string>bkahblahblah</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```